# systemd equivalent of upstart's "respawn limit"

Tags: systemd

I am trying to make a systemd file that will monitor a service and restart it if it crashes. Here's the tricky part: If the service crashes more than 5 times in a minute, I want to mark it as failed and stop trying to automatically restart it. With Upstart, this was easily done with "respawn limit."

Systemd can rate-limit the automatic restarting with StartLimitIntervalSec, but that's not what I want.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate at serverfault.com.  As it is I'm not sure it's programming-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. For systemd questions, the [Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) site is a more appropriate placeto ask in the future.

It appears that you are looking for `StartLimitInterval=60`, which allows you to set the number of seconds to limit by. Around `systemd` version 230, this is renamed to `StartLimitIntervalSec=`.

This would be combined with `StartLimitBurst=5` to set a max of 5 starts per minute.

There's also `StartLimitAction` but it default to the value of `none`, which already does what you want in this case.

You can find these documented in `man systemd.unit`. If you aren't sure where to find documentation on a directive, you can use `man systemd.directive` to find where any directive is documented.

Comment: I apologize for posting in the wrong place. I will re-post there. However, StartLimitIntervalSec is not what I'm looking for. It simply rate-limits the automatic starts. I want the service to give up and go into a failed state if the limit gets hit, rather than just trying again the next minute. That's what "respawn limit" does.

Comment: Did you read about `StartLimitAction=` in the official documentation as I suggested. It states quite clearly that it will quit trying to start the app: "If
  'none' is set [the default], hitting the rate limit will trigger no action besides that the start will not be permitted. "

Comment: I don't understand how this is the accepted solution. `StartLimitAction=none` (which is also the default) will not stop the service from restarting, it just means to do nothing extra every time the start rate is exceeded. The service will continue restarting forever, adhering to the specified rate.